Error When Adding Package to flutter and run in Android
when I run Flutter with no package or dependency it will run with no error.
but when I run flutter with any package or dependency it makes an error like this.
Launching lib\main.dart on moto g34 5G in debug mode...
Warning: SDK processing. This version only understands SDK XML versions up to 3 but an SDK XML file of version 4 was encountered. This can happen if you use versions of Android Studio and the command-line tools that were released at different times.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':shared_preferences_android:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':shared_preferences_android:androidJdkImage'.
   > Failed to transform core-for-system-modules.jar to match attributes {artifactType=_internal_android_jdk_image, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
      > Execution failed for JdkImageTransform: C:\Users\Kannan\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platforms\android-34\core-for-system-modules.jar.
         > Error while executing process C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jbr\bin\jlink.exe with arguments {--module-path C:\Users\Kannan\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\4a46fc89ed5f9adfe3afebf74eb8bfeb\transformed\output\temp\jmod --add-modules java.base --output C:\Users\Kannan\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\4a46fc89ed5f9adfe3afebf74eb8bfeb\transformed\output\jdkImage --disable-plugin system-modules}

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.


I tried the following methods but didn't work
flutter clean
flutter upgrade
flutter pub get
and tried to run another platform like windows rather than android . and it worked in windows

only "shared_preferences" package is creating prb.  1. update ur "command-line tools" from android sdk tool 2. if still shows error then degrade ur shared preference version

This issue is because of  version compatibility between your Android Studio and the SDK versions you're using to fix your problem you can try->

version compatibility between your Android Studio and the SDK versions you're using.

2)Update Android studio.
3)Check Gradle Version->gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties.

Update Shared Preferences.
this will solve your problem.


issue not solved
